# Where does WordPress get it’s daylight savings info

Tags: php, utc, dst, timezone-offset

My question is, where does WordPress get the data from relating to automatic Timezone and DST change and how can I implement the same principal into converting a web app users selected local date and time into stored offsets to allow for their movement back and forward of clocks during daylight saving?

Obviously I can store this as UTC and then convert the time to their local Timezone on the fly, but this will still not accurately reflect the date and time they entered if they are in the opposite daylight savings setting as when the record was created. I am using asp.net c# with a sql server.

WordPress automatically reflects daylight saving time by selecting a city, not offset hours in WP-admin > Settings > General > Timezone. You will then see a notification like this:

```
This timezone is currently in daylight saving time.

Standard time begins on: Sunday 25.10. 04:00,
```

It is somewhere in the code of /wp-admin/options-general.php

```
<?php
$current_offset = get_option('gmt_offset');
$tzstring = get_option('timezone_string');

$check_zone_info = true;

// Remove old Etc mappings. Fallback to gmt_offset.
if ( false !== strpos($tzstring,'Etc/GMT') )
$tzstring = '';

if ( empty($tzstring) ) { // Create a UTC+- zone if no timezone string exists
$check_zone_info = false;
if ( 0 == $current_offset )
    $tzstring = 'UTC+0';
elseif ($current_offset < 0)
    $tzstring = 'UTC' . $current_offset;
else
    $tzstring = 'UTC+' . $current_offset;
}

?>
<th scope="row"><label for="timezone_string"><?php _e('Timezone') ?></label></th>
<td>

<select id="timezone_string" name="timezone_string" aria-describedby="timezone-description">
<?php echo wp_timezone_choice( $tzstring, get_user_locale() ); ?>
</select>

<p class="description" id="timezone-description"><?php _e( 'Choose either a city in the same timezone as you or a UTC timezone offset.' ); ?></p>

<p class="timezone-info">
<span id="utc-time"><?php
    /* translators: 1: UTC abbreviation, 2: UTC time */
    printf( __( 'Universal time (%1$s) is %2$s.' ),
        '<abbr>' . __( 'UTC' ) . '</abbr>',
        '<code>' . date_i18n( $timezone_format, false, true ) . '</code>'
    );
?></span>
<?php if ( get_option( 'timezone_string' ) || ! empty( $current_offset ) ) : ?>
<span id="local-time"><?php
    /* translators: %s: local time */
    printf( __( 'Local time is %s.' ),
        '<code>' . date_i18n( $timezone_format ) . '</code>'
    );
?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
</p>

<?php if ( $check_zone_info && $tzstring ) : ?>
<p class="timezone-info">
<span>
<?php
// Set TZ so localtime works.
date_default_timezone_set($tzstring);
$now = localtime(time(), true);
if ( $now['tm_isdst'] )
    _e('This timezone is currently in daylight saving time.');
else
    _e('This timezone is currently in standard time.');
?>
<br />
<?php
$allowed_zones = timezone_identifiers_list();

if ( in_array( $tzstring, $allowed_zones) ) {
    $found = false;
    $date_time_zone_selected = new DateTimeZone($tzstring);
    $tz_offset = timezone_offset_get($date_time_zone_selected, date_create());
    $right_now = time();
    foreach ( timezone_transitions_get($date_time_zone_selected) as $tr) {
        if ( $tr['ts'] > $right_now ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $found ) {
        echo ' ';
        $message = $tr['isdst'] ?
            /* translators: %s: date and time  */
            __( 'Daylight saving time begins on: %s.')  :
            /* translators: %s: date and time  */
            __( 'Standard time begins on: %s.' );
        // Add the difference between the current offset and the new offset to ts to get the correct transition time from date_i18n().
        printf( $message,
            '<code>' . date_i18n(
                __( 'F j, Y' ) . ' ' . __( 'g:i a' ),
                $tr['ts'] + ( $tz_offset - $tr['offset'] )
            ) . '</code>'
        );
    } else {
        _e( 'This timezone does not observe daylight saving time.' );
    }
}
// Set back to UTC.
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
?>
</span>
```

Comment: Are these the droids you are looking for? `$current_offset = get_option('gmt_offset');`
`$tzstring = get_option('timezone_string'); `

Comment: Should remove the C# tag, kind of just tangential that it's in your project, has nothing to do with real question, I think.

Comment: Hi @IanRay, yes those are probably the guilty parties but how does it work? How does it know the offset required and how does the function work to automatically change the date and time for the respective DST? I know its probably processed as part of the CRON, just don't understand how this function works and obtains the data to reflect that Auckland NZ is currently in Daylight Saving, Melbourne, Australia start's theirs on a particular date, and that Brisbane AU does not have DST at all.

Comment: I would venture a guess that because Daylight Savings Time is an equation with no external variables.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Daylight_saving_in_time_zone/techdoc  Therefore they can just implement it on the back end and it always works.  They would just look up what timezone the user is accessing from via IP information, and the Wordpress DateTime libraries likely account for it when they present the 'timezone_string'.  Hopefully I've answered your question.

Comment: I don't think that's what you're looking for. `gmt_offset` and `timezone_string` are just values stored in the database. If the user selects `America/Vancouver` from the TZ dropdown, then `America/Vancouver` will be stored in `timezone_string`. If they select `UTC-9:00` from the dropdown, then `-9` will be stored in `gmt_offset`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$now = localtime(time(), true);
if ( $now['tm_isdst'] )
    _e('This timezone is currently in daylight saving time.');
else
    _e('This timezone is currently in standard time.');
```

I would use the localtime function, whatever library that comes out of.

--edit-- 
I would also note the lines:

```
// Set TZ so localtime works.
date_default_timezone_set($tzstring);
```

those will probably be necessary, I don't know, I don't write PHP.

Comment: To a degree, yes... Though I'm struggling to work out why it's so difficult to get an accurate read of the user's location + timezone + dst so I can store the relevant offsets and store the time as utc in one database column, then add the locOffset from another column, then add or remove the DST offset from a third column. Would be so much easier if everyone lived in the same timezone!

Comment: Please select this as the correct answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Use of date_default_timezone_set() and standard timezone-aware PHP time functions is heavily discouraged in WordPress. WP itself always sets date_default_timezone_set('UTC'), and relies on this being the case. While some plugins set the timezone to do some calculations, and then restore it afterwards, this is not recommended. WP provides its own functions such as wp_date() and date_i18n() which should be used instead.